Read PDF from stripe portal
I am having this URL
https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_1OtiZXH7y1vTRsp1/test_YWNjdF8xT3RpWlhIN3kxdlRSc3AxLF9RMkxNanIzNXN3TTlZOHNaaUZLZm9kQnBjemh3STBXLDEwNTI2NDAzOA0200luNre0xP/pdf?s=ap

and when we click on the above strip URL directly in browser then a PDF file will be downloaded but I want to download the same content using APEX and have to store in content version against a contact.
I tried many way to dowlad the content like
string url = 'https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_1OtiZXH7y1vTRsp1/test_YWNjdF8xT3RpWlhIN3kxdlRSc3AxLF9RMkxNanIzNXN3TTlZOHNaaUZLZm9kQnBjemh3STBXLDEwNTI2NDAzOA0200luNre0xP/pdf?s=ap';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
String responseBody = res.getBody();

But I am getting empty body
even I am not getting any blob if I tried like this also
   Blob pdfBlob = res.getBodyAsBlob();

If the URL is directly as
https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/pdf/example.pdf

then the above code is working.

What does 'res.getStatusCode()` show?

Specifically, you're looking to see if you're getting a status code like 302 (a redirect) which would indicate that you need to make another callout to get the actual data using the data in the location header. Using the developer tools (network tab) in your browser would be another way to see what's happening. It's also possible that you could be getting a4xx error like a 403 which would indicate that you probably need an api key or access token (via OAuth), but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Thanks @sfdcfox  ,Derek Got some input from this 302 and achived the output through this
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
req.setEndpoint(res.getHeader('Location'));
res = http.send(req);
Blob pdfBlob = res.getBodyAsBlob();

That was my suspicion, too. Glad you could get the help you needed. Don't forget to accept Derek's answer.

Callouts from Apex do not follow redirects (status code 3xx, in general).
In the case of your 302 status code, you'll need to take the url provided in the location header of the HttpResponse from the first callout, and perform another callout.
